# Not sure what this button class is doing in the code for a navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I copied the code for a navbar from getbootstrap.com and I'm having trouble understanding what the code for the button.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The code for the button is in lines 3 to 7. Not sure what its purpose is in the navbar as there's already an anchor tag in place.

Also what does the code `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">` do, specifically the classes 'collapse' and 'navbar-collapse'. When I delete them, they don't seem to make any difference (I haven't fully implemented the webpage yet though so that might be why).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is going to toggle(hide & show) the navbar

Comment: Just resize your browser window to make it very small and you will see its effect. Try with and without this code to see the difference.

Comment: Got it, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the button is for small and medium screen sizes it will be the hamburger button [image: button]